# How to predict or calculate the file-size of an image (NSImage) when written to disk?

Tags: file, nsfilemanager, nsimage, swift4.2

The question say's it all.

How can I predict in Swift4.2 or at least in Swift4 the file-size of an image in an NSImage or NSImageView.image?

I can't find anything about this is the Apple docs.

Should I convert it to some kind of (NS)Data representation or...

..should I save the image to disk, check the size with FileManager, do my thing, and resave the file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will require to convert the image to Data, try this may help you:

```
    let image = UIImage(named: "example.jpg")
    if let _data = image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
    {
        print("Size: \(_data.count) bytes")
    }
```

Comment: Thats for ios UIImage and not macos NSImage

Comment: I have not much idea on this but try below code :

var rep = image.representations()[0] as? NSImageRep;
var imageSize: NSSize = NSMakeSize(rep?.pixelsWide, rep?.pixelsHigh)